# How do I compare an integer to a character when trying to look at each's ASCII value in Java

Tags: java, string, character, radix

So, I am making a program for doing arithmetic with multiple bases (meaning binary up to haxidecimal and all of the in-between), and since I am still relatively new to Java, I am having a bit of a hard time trying to figure out exactly how to make the comparison I want.  What I would like to do is take the last character in the string and compare it to a specific integer.  For example, say I have 9.54126 for a number. Well, at this point in the program this number is actually a string of characters, so I am looking at the '6' at the end as a character.  I want to see if that six is high enough to round up or not.  So, essentially I am looking to see if it's ASCII value is higher than half of the current base (if the answer is to be shown in base 15 or 16, I round up at 8 and so on).  Earlier in the program I found the value it should be rounded at based on what the current chosen base is and saved it in the integer variable roundable.  Now, I need to know how to compare the ASCII values of the integer as a character, and the character in the last spot.  Here is example code:

```
 //roundable is an integer here but I want it to be the character representation
 //of the number so I can compare their ASCII values                                                        

if(convertedString.charAt(lastSpot)) >= roundable){
    //round here
} else {
    //don't round
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, your convertedString contains only character from `'0'-'9'`: you just could easily do,

```
lastSpot = convertedString.length() - 1;
roundable = base/2;
if((convertedString.charAt(lastSpot) - '0') >= roundable){
    //round here
} else {
    //don't round
}
```

hex(decimal) value of `'0'` is `30(48)` in  and for `'9'` is `39(57)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int base;
String number;

boolean roundUp = number.charAt(number.length() - 1) - '0' > base / 2;
```